# Next Previous Post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i show the content in next previous post of wordpress. For example. For the next post link with title is to be there, Is it possible to show the content of that post (100 Words).

```
       <div class="alignleftfp">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', '%title'); ?>
<?php get_next_post();?>
        </div>
        <div class="alignrightfp">
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title'); ?>
<?php get_previous_post();?>
        </div>
```

Much appreciated if any response. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's within The Loop, you can use [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) or [`get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_excerpt) depending on your requirements.

If it's outside The Loop, you can use a function like this to get the post excerpt by the post ID:

```
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
    $the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
    $the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
    $excerpt_length = 35; //Sets excerpt length by word count
    $the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images
    $words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);

    if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
        array_pop($words);
        array_push($words, '…');
        $the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
    endif;

    $the_excerpt = '<p>' . $the_excerpt . '</p>';

    return $the_excerpt;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't get any content while using get_previous_post

Answer (score 2):

[get_next_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) and [get_previous_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) should help you out.

Comment: I didn't get any content on the particular post why

Comment: OK try e.g.:
`
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
`

Answer (score 0):

```
function content($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
}   
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $content;
}
```

In post page , enter the words limit like this--> echo content(100).
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following functions

For next post link

```
<?php next_post_link('format', 'link', 'in_same_cat', 'excluded_categories'); ?>
```

For previous post link

```
<?php previous_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="post-navigation">
        <div class="prev-post">
            <?php $greenres_prev_post = get_previous_post();
            if($greenres_prev_post):
                ?>
                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($greenres_prev_post);
                    ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($greenres_prev_post); ?></a></h3>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="next-post">
            <?php $greenres_next_post = get_next_post();
            if($greenres_next_post):
            ?>
            <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($greenres_next_post);
                ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($greenres_next_post); ?></a></h3>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```